# C++ tr1 shared_ptr with custom allocator and deleter

Tags: c++, memory-management, constructor, shared-ptr

I am using tr1 shared_ptr (work not yet updated to C++0x or C++11) and I need
to use std::tr1::shared_ptr with a class Foo that has a custom allocator and deleter.

Currently Foo is allocated/deallocated by the following code:

```
void createFoo(Foo** mem) {
 *mem = (Foo *) malloc(sizeof(Foo));
  memset(*mem, 0, sizeof(Foo));
}
```

and

```
void deleteFoo(Foo* mem) {
  // code to call recursive methods to delete Foo substructures
  memset(...)
}
```

How do I declare a `std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo>` using createFoo and deleteFoo ?

Comment: Why doesn't `createFoo` simply return the value of `malloc` instead of through a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: Any reason for doing it that way in C++? Have you thought about overloading operators `new` and `delete`?

Comment: `deleteFoo` isn’t releasing any memory! …

Comment: @Konrad: I left out the code to actually free the memory: it is mentioned in the comment.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: No particular reason - this is how I find the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't change `createFoo` (which would be preferable) then you're going to want to wrap the `createFoo` to hide that double pointer:

```
#include <memory>

struct Foo {};

void createFoo(Foo **p) { *p = new Foo; }
void deleteFoo(Foo *p) { delete p; }

std::shared_ptr<Foo> wrapCreateFoo() {
  Foo *p = NULL;
  createFoo(&p);
  return std::shared_ptr<Foo>(p, deleteFoo);
}

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<Foo> f = wrapCreateFoo();
}
```

I did it all in one place since `wrapCreateFoo` returning a `shared_ptr` makes it harder to forget to set the correct deleter function.

I used the C++11 header/namespace for `shared_ptr` in my example, but it's identical for the TR1/Boost case.